# подсветка строки если совпадает значение

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование

если sql таблица которая выводится, хочу сделать подсветку строк если совпадают значения в столбце, но как-т оне совесм понимаю как это реализовать на html\php\css так как нуб в вебе еще. Если правильно понимаю код должен выглядеть как-то так (код естественно не работающий:) ):

```
 foreach($result as $key=>$val)
{
  $data .= '<tr>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Inventory_LLC'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Inventory_DD'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetCategory'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetType'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetSubtype'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Transfer_Date'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Return_Date'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['UniqID'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Owner'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Comp'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Location'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Status'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Status'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Entry'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['SN'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Notes'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['CR_IMEI'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Org_Unit'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Position'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Cost'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Any_Val'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Pur_Date'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Check_Uncheck'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Local_Material'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['PO'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Activated'].'</td>';
  $data .= '</tr>';

    if ($val['Asset_Status']=='01_Active') {
        background-color:#00ff00;
      }

}
```

Comment: а что за `$val['Asset_Status']`? что находится в `$val`?

Comment: данные из таблицы

Comment: `var_dump($val)` - и покажите нам результат, и что должно подсвечиваться.

Comment: bool(true) или bool(false) в зависимости от строки, надо чтобы когда bool(true) оно подсвечивало всю строку с данным значением

Comment: Лично я вас не понимаю, сформулируйте конкретно задачу: есть такая-то строка (или массив), есть такая-то строка, и надо сделать что-то. Доступно сформируйте задачу. Мы рядом с вами там не сидим не понимаем о чем речь.

Comment: @Manitikyl, я добавил цикл вывода таблицы, может так будет понятнее, я просто хочу при выводе красить строки в разные цвета для облегчения роботы с таблицой

Comment: В самом низу моего ответа, так вам надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать на стороне сервера, то вот пример:

```
// Наша строка
$HTML = 'Раз два три четыре пять';
// Наше слово
$SEARCH = 'два';
// Паттерн
$PATTERN = "/((?:^|>)[^<]*)(".$SEARCH.")/is";
// Подсвечиваем результат
$REPLACE = '$1<b style="color:#FF0000; background:#FFFF00;">$2</b>';
// Заменяем
$HTML = preg_replace($PATTERN, $REPLACE, $HTML);
// Любуемся результатом
echo $HTML;
```

Для цикла :<

```
// Массив с текстом
$ARRAY = [
    'Строка 1: Раз два три четыре пять.',
    'Строка 2: Раз два три четыре пять.',
    'Строка 3: Раз два три четыре пять.'
];
// Наше слово
$SEARCH = 'два';
// Паттерн
$PATTERN = "/((?:^|>)[^<]*)(".$SEARCH.")/is";
// Подсвеченная строка
$REPLACE = '$1<b style="color:#FF0000; background:#FFFF00;">$2</b>';
// Цикл
foreach ($ARRAY as $HTML) {
    // Заменяем
    $HTML = preg_replace($PATTERN, $REPLACE, $HTML);
    // Любуемся результатом
    echo $HTML;
}
```

**Правка:**

У вас есть такая строка:

```
$data .= '<tr>';
```

Замените ее на:

```
if ($val['Asset_Status']=='01_Active') {
    $data .= '<tr style="background-color:#00ff00;">';
}else{
    $data .= '<tr>';
}
```

Comment: а если делать сразу в цикле вывода на страницу?

Comment: @Elanyl так делайте, кто вам запрещает?

Comment: заменил, из таблицы пропали все строки с 01_Active

Comment: @Elanyl обновите свой ответ и покажите что у вас получилось.